# Can an API return entire JSON data structure from another API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest

I am using ASP.NET core to build an REST API which processes data from another Rest API.

My question: how would I get everything from https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all and return it in JSON format in my own API? I am then going to get only the currencies.

Would this be easier in a different language? This is my first API.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, it is possible. In order to call an `api` you should use `HttpClient` and then return its `output` to client. below is an example of how you can do it in `ASP.NET Core`

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
        };

        var responseTask =await client.GetAsync("");
        var jsonResult = await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return Json(jsonResult);
    }
```

Finally, if you want to get just specific item in your json data, you can use some library like `NewtonSoft`

Comment: Hi, this has worked for the most part but I think it is returning it as a string so it returns just 1 huge line of JSON.

Comment: Json is a string so all you need it pass that string to client. you want to return it as another type?

Answer (score 0):

In any language the process will be the same. In the controller that handles the call to your API, use a request library to make the call to the external resource, extract it's JSON payload into your own local variable, process it as you like, and then return it as your own response.